# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^0 \log(\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(x))\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, error-function

I am looking to evaluate

> $$\int_{-\infty}^0 \log\left(\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(x)\right)\mathrm dx = -0.337~668~477...$$

Both Maple and Mathematica have failed to give a closed-form expression but indicate the value is around $−0.337~668~477...$ which doesn't appear to be close to some well known quantity.

Comment: What exactly is $\operatorname{erfc}(x)$, i.e. how do you define it in this context?

Comment: @mrtaurho It is the complementary error function $\operatorname{erfc}(x) = 1-\operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$ as found in e.g http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html

Comment: How do you know that there is an explicit closed form for this integral?

Comment: @FrankW. I do not know that a closed form exists but would very much hope it did. I don't really know of any helpful heuristics to determine if a closed form exists when the integrand is composed of non-elementary functions.

Comment: I really do hope there is a closed form solution... I'm lost at this stage as to how it could be found.

Answer (score 7):

$\textbf{Edition of 19.02.19}$

Is known, that

> $$\begin{cases}
> \operatorname{erf}x = \dfrac2{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt,\quad
> \operatorname{erfc}x = \dfrac2{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt,\\[4pt]
> \operatorname{erf}(-\infty) = -1,\quad 
> \operatorname{erf}(0) = 0,\quad 
> \operatorname{erf}(\infty) = 1,\\[4pt]
> \operatorname{erf}(-x) = - \operatorname{erf}x,\quad 
> \operatorname{erfc}x = 1-\operatorname{erf}x,\quad
> \operatorname{erfc}(-x)+\operatorname{erfc}(x) = 2,\\[4pt]
> \operatorname{erfc}(-\infty) = 2,\quad 
> \operatorname{erfc}(0) = 1,\quad 
> \operatorname{erfc}(\infty) = 0.\tag1
> \end{cases}$$

So
$$I=\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 \log\left(\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(x)\right)\mathrm dx 
= \int\limits_{-\infty}^0 \log\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(-x)\right)\mathrm dx
=\int\limits_0^\infty \log\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(x)\right)\mathrm dx,$$ 
or, using Maclaurin series for logarithm in the form of

> $$\log(1-x)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}n,\tag2$$

$$I=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{2^n n} I_n,\tag3$$
wherein
\begin{align}
&I_n=\int\limits_0^\infty\operatorname{erfc}^n(x)\,\mathrm dx 
= \operatorname{erfc}^{n}(x)\cdot x\Bigg|_0^\infty
-\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty x e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erfc}^{n-1}(x)\,\mathrm dx,\\[4pt]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_n = \dfrac{2n}{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty x e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erfc}^{n-1}(x)\,\mathrm dx,\tag{4.1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_1 = \dfrac2{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty\,x e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx 
= \dfrac1{\sqrt\pi}\approx0.56418\,95835\,47756,\tag{5.1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_n= \dfrac{n}{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \operatorname{erfc}^{n-1}(x)\,\mathrm d e^{-x^2}\\[4pt]
&= \dfrac{n}{\sqrt\pi}\operatorname{erfc}^{n-1}(x)\,e^{-x^2} \Bigg|_0^\infty
- \dfrac{2n(n-1)}\pi \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x^2}\operatorname{erfc}^{n-2}(x)\,\mathrm dx\\[4pt]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_n = \dfrac{n}{\sqrt\pi} - \dfrac{2n(n-1)}\pi \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x^2}\operatorname{erfc}^{n-2}(x)\,\mathrm dx,\quad n\geq2,\tag{4.2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_2 = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt\pi} - \dfrac4\pi \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x^2}\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt\pi} - \sqrt{\dfrac2\pi} \operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)\Bigg|_0^\infty,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_2 = \int\limits_0^\infty\operatorname{erfc}^2(x)\,\mathrm dx = \dfrac{2-\sqrt2}{\sqrt\pi}\approx0.33049\,46062\,92647,\tag{5.2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_3 = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt\pi} - \dfrac{12}\pi \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x^2}\operatorname{erfc}(x)\,\mathrm dx,\\[4pt]
& \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x^2}\operatorname{erfc}(x)\,\mathrm dx
= \dfrac1{\sqrt2} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x^2}\operatorname{erfc}(x)\,\mathrm d(x\sqrt2)
=\dfrac1{\sqrt2} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\dfrac x{\sqrt2}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\[4pt]
& = \sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_{\frac x{\sqrt2}}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx
= \sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_{\arctan\frac1{\sqrt2}}^{\large\frac\pi2} e^{-\rho^2}\rho \,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\varphi= \dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\arctan\sqrt2
,\\[4pt]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I_3 = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt\pi} - \dfrac{6\sqrt2}{\pi\sqrt\pi}\arctan\sqrt2\approx 0.23681\ 21373\ 68199\tag{5.3}
\end{align}
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2Fsqrt%20pi%20-12%2Fpi%20int_0%5Einfty%20(e%5E(-2x%5E2)%20erfc(x)%20)%20dx)).

[Numerical calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einfty%20(%20sum_(n%3D1)%5E(20)%20(erfc(x))%5En%2F(n%202%5En))%20dx) confirm the correctness of the formula $(3).$
But it was not possible to get a closed form of $I_n$ for $n>3.$

At the same time, the integration of the issue integral by parts gives
\begin{align}
&I=\int\limits_0^\infty \log\left(1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x)\right)\mathrm dx 
= \log\left(1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x)\right)\cdot x\Bigg|_0^\infty
-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{xe^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx}{1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x)},\\[4pt]
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{xe^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx}{1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x)},\tag6
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \left(1 + \frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x) + \frac14\operatorname{erfc}^2(x) + \frac18\operatorname{erfc}^3(x) + \dots+\frac1{2^k}\operatorname{erfc}^k(x)+\dots\right) xe^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\[4pt]
&= -\left(\dfrac12I_1+\dfrac18I_2+\dfrac1{24}I_3 +\frac1{8\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\operatorname{erfc}^3(x)\,xe^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx}{1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x)}\right)\\[4pt]
& = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\left(\frac12+\dfrac{2-\sqrt2}8+\dfrac1{24}\left(3-\dfrac{6\sqrt2\,\arctan\sqrt2}\pi\right) +\dfrac18\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\operatorname{erfc}^3(x)\,xe^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx}{1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x)}\right),
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&I = -\frac1{8\sqrt\pi}\left(7-\sqrt2\left(1+\dfrac2\pi\arctan\sqrt2\right) +\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\operatorname{erfc}^3(x)\,xe^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx}{1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc}(x)}\right)\tag7
\end{align}
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F(8sqrt%20pi)(7-sqrt2(1%2B2%2Fpi%20arctan%20sqrt%202)%2Bint_0%5Einfty%20x%20e%5E(-x%5E2)%20(erfc%20x)%5E3%2F(1-erfc%20x%20%2F2)%20dx)))

On the other hand,
\begin{align}
&I=-\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{xe^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx}{1 +\operatorname{erf}(x)}
=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\mathrm de^{-x^2}}{1+\operatorname{erf}(x)}\\[4pt]  
&=\frac1{\sqrt\pi} \dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{\left(1+\operatorname{erf}(x)\right)}\Bigg|_0^\infty
+\frac2\pi\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\mathrm e^{-2x^2}}{\left(1+\operatorname{erf}(x)\right)^2}\mathrm dx\  
=\frac2{\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\mathrm e^{-2x^2}}{\left(1+\operatorname{erf}(x)\right)^2}\mathrm dx-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\\[4pt]
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\mathrm d\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)}{\left(1+\operatorname{erf}(x)\right)^2}
-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\dfrac{\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)}{\left(1+\operatorname{erf}(x)\right)^2}\Bigg|_0^\infty
+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot2\cdot\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)}{\left(1+\operatorname{erf}(x)\right)^3}\,\mathrm dx
-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2\sqrt2}\pi\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)}{\left(1+\operatorname{erf}(x)\right)^3}\,\mathrm dx-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}+\frac1{4\sqrt{2\pi}}.\\[4pt]  
\end{align}
Binomial decomposition in the form of

> $$\dfrac1{(1-y)^{m+1}} = \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\binom nm y^{n-m}\tag8$$

allows the further transformations in the form of
$$\begin{align}
&I = \frac 1{2\pi\sqrt2}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)}{\left(1-\frac12\operatorname{erfc} x\right)^3}\,\mathrm dx-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}+\frac1{4\sqrt{2\pi}}\\[4pt]  
& = \frac 1{2\pi\sqrt2}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2^{n-2}}\,\operatorname{erfc}^{n-2} x\,\mathrm dx-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}+\frac1{4\sqrt{2\pi}}\\[4pt]  
& = \frac 1{2\pi\sqrt2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2^n}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)\,\operatorname{erfc}^n x\,\mathrm dx-\frac1{\sqrt\pi}+\frac1{4\sqrt{2\pi}},
\end{align}$$

$$I = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi}+\frac1{4\sqrt{2\pi}} + \dfrac{\arctan\sqrt2}{2\pi\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac 1{2\pi\sqrt2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2^n}J_n,\tag9$$
where
$$J_n=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x\sqrt2)\,\operatorname{erfc}^n x\,\mathrm dx\tag{10}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(64%20pi%20sqrt2)%20int_0%5Einfty%20erf(x%20sqrt2)e%5E(-x%5E2)erfc%20x%5E%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%7D%20dx.%7B48,48,40,30,21,14,9,%2045%2F8%7D%20-1%2Fsqrt%20pi%20%2B1%2F(4sqrt(2pi))%20%2B%20(arctan%20sqrt2)%2F(2pi)%5E(3%2F2))).

Besides, can be used the presentations
$$\begin{align}
&I = \frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\mathrm d(e^{-x^2})}{1+\operatorname{erfc}(x)}
 = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{\mathrm dz}{1+\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{-\log z})},
\end{align}$$
wherein
$$\dfrac1{1+\operatorname{erf}\sqrt{-\log \dfrac{\sqrt\pi y}2}} =\dfrac1{1+y}\left(1+\dfrac\pi{12}\dfrac{y^3}{1+y}\left(1+\dfrac\pi{120}\dfrac{y^3-9y^2}{1+y}\right)\right)+\dots$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B1%2F(1%2Berf(sqrt%20pi%2F2%20%20y))-1%2F(1%2By)(1%2B%20pi%2F12%20y%5E3%2F(1%2By)(1%2Bpi%2F120%20(y%5E3-9y%5E2)%2F(1%2By)))%7D,%7By,0,1.0%7D)).

However, closed form was not obtained.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any simple formula. More precise evaluation yields (check 'WorkingPrecision' if using Mathematica):

$-0.3376684770344218621827398500$

This can be reverse looked up using this nice page:
 [here](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.337668477034421862182739850053&lookup_type=simple),
which checks it against (a **lot** of) symbolic expressions evaluated very precisely. No hits there, so if anything it'll probably be a rather complicated expression.

This is by no means conclusive. Good luck on Your hunt!

Answer (score 0):

$\def\erfc{\operatorname{erfc}} \def\H{\operatorname H} $

Substitute $\erfc(x)\to x$ and integrate by parts to get the [inverse $\erfc$ function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErfc.html):

$$\int_{-\infty}^0\ln\left(\frac{\erfc(x)}2\right)dx=\int_1^2\ln \left(\frac x2\right)d(\erfc^{-1}(x))=\int_1^2\frac{\erfc^{-1}(x)}xdx$$

Next, use [$\erfc^{-1}(x)$’s series expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErfc/06/01/02/0004/) valid for $0\le x\le 2$ as [implied by Quantile Mechanics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEKVU.jpg):

$$\int_1^2\frac{\erfc^{-1}(x)}xdx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{2n+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\right)^{2n+1}\int_1^2\frac{(x-1)^{2n+1}}xdx;a_0=1,a_n=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_ma_{n-m-1}}{(2m+1)(m+1)}$$

Finally, apply the [harmonic numbers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=HarmonicNumber%28n%29):

$$\int_1^2\frac{(x-1)^{2n+1}}xdx=\frac12\left(\H_{n+\frac12}-\H_n\right)$$

Therefore:

$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^0\ln\left(\frac{\erfc(x)}2\right)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{\H_n-\H_{n+\frac12}}{4n+2}\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\right)^{2n+1} ;a_0=1,a_n=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_ma_{n-m-1}}{(2m+1)(m+1)}}$$

Unfortunately, the partial sums show slow convergence. The Mathematica code used was:

`Normal[Series[InverseErfc[x],{x,1,a}]]`

`NIntegrate[%b/x,{x,1,2}]`

Corresponding to the $b$th output and $\lceil\frac a2\rceil$th partial sum:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}n&\text{Approximation}\\50&-0.336631\\100&-0.337175\\150&-0.337349\\193&-0.337424\\\end{matrix}\right]$$